# "In Zeiten da" vs. "in denen"

Tags: difference

> In Zeiten, **da/in denen** Menschen per Mausklick alles kaufen können, erscheint solch ein Vorschlag durchaus vernünftig.

Was ist hier richtig? Oder ist beides richtig? Und wenn ja, was kommt häufiger vor?

Comment: Zu diesem Thema gibt es ein gutes Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjVOwiKDENo.

Comment: Häufiger geschrieben, gesprochen, bezogen auf eine bestimmte Schicht/Region? Welchen Zeitraum betrachten wir und woher sollen wir das wissen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es ist beides richtig. Die Verwendung von "da" als temporale Konjunktion in der Bedeutung von "als" gilt allerdings laut Duden als "gehoben veraltend", kommt also wesentlich seltener vor. Ich kann das aus meiner Spracherfahrung bestätigen.

Die warscheinlich bekannteste Verwendung, die man mindestens einmal im Jahr zu hören bekommt, stammt aus der Bibel Lukas 2, 1-20, der Weihnachtsgeschichte:

> Und diese Schätzung war die allererste und geschah zur Zeit, da Quirinius Statthalter in Syrien war.